# I am getting Operation not allowed after Result Set closed

Tags: java, sql, exception

I am extracting about 10,000 patient ids and at the same time after performing encryption I want to insert them in a different table but I am getting this error

> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed.

```
Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;
try{
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(constring,username,password);
    System.out.println("connected");

    Statement stmt=(Statement) conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet srs = stmt.executeQuery(
    "select patient_id from patient");

    while (srs.next()) {
        patient_id = srs.getInt("patient_id");

        System.out.println(patient_id);
        JavaApplication5 o=new JavaApplication5(key);

        g=patient_id;
        o.c=main.g;
        s=o.encrypt(o.c,key);
        System.out.println(s);
        String insert = "Insert into fyp1 (patient_id) values ('"+s+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(insert);
        }
    }
catch(SQLException e){System.out.println(e);
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with Java, but since you're iterating over `stmt`, which is the results of one query, it seems unlikely to me that you can simultaneously repurpose `stmt` to issue a second query. I think you'll need a second object to use for the insert statements.

Comment: the sql sentence (select) is true? And I think you must use PrepareStatement instead of Statement.

Comment: I believe Jeff Rosenberg is correct. Also don't forget to close opened resources, as they can cause leaks (not only to your application but also in this case the database server). try-resource block is available long ago

Comment: [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) to the rescue: *All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a current ResultSet object of the statement if an open one exists.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another Statement since the first ResultSet `srs` is closed when it is run again at `stmt.executeUpdate(insert);`.

See in the JavaDocs for [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close%28%29)

> Note: A ResultSet object is automatically closed by the Statement object that generated it when that Statement object is closed, re-executed, or is used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

Btw. Please post always the full stacktrace e.g. with the corresponding line numbers.